# Umbrella Header for Module Bolts does not include header 'BFAppLinkResolving.h'

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, xcode6, bolts-framework

I'm running an xcode 6.3 project with Parse 1.7.1 (newest version), Swift. I'm getting this issue being raised on my builds. My autocomplete and typing is PAINFULLY slow and I think it maybe related. I've testing out projects and it only happens when the Bolts module is in the project (which is required for Parse).

Comment: What's an umbrella header or framework? It's the first time I see it. Thanks.

Comment: Currently the latest version of the iOS Parse SDK is 1.7.5 and this problem is fixed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @MaddTheSane pointed, the Bolts framework is missing the `modulemap` in the last update of Parse (1.7.1).

In the Bolts.Framework create `Modules/` (if it does not exist) and inside it create a file `module.modulemap` with the content shown below. I will suggest removing the current Bolts framework from your project and importing again (the modified one.)

[image]

```
framework module Bolts {
umbrella header "Bolts.h"

export *
module * { export * }


explicit module BFAppLinkResolving {
    header "BFAppLinkResolving.h"
    link "BFAppLinkResolving"
    export *
}}
```

Answer (score 15):

@franciscodlp - We also need to add another header file (BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.h) - I had to make 2 of them explicit. Below is how the module.modulemap should look like.

```
framework module Bolts {
  umbrella header "Bolts.h"

  export *
  module * { export * }

  explicit module BFAppLinkResolving {
    header "BFAppLinkResolving.h"
    link "BFAppLinkResolving"
    export *
  }
  explicit module BFWebViewAppLinkResolver {
      header "BFWebViewAppLinkResolver.h"
      link "BFAWebViewAppLinkResolver"
      export *
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the Bolts framework have a module file in it? if not, you most likely need to import Bolt's umbrella header (and `BFAppLinkResolving.h`) in your bridging header.

Unless you are using functions that are in that header, you can ignore the warning.

I would recommend that you contact the developers of Bolts and Parse, as they may be able to offer better help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm building a Swift project and linking the Parse SDK through Cocoapods, and I got the `Module 'Bolts' not found` message. Looks like the Bolts pod didn't include a Swift module, but putting

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
```

in `{project-name}-Bridging-Header.h` resolved my issue.